# Is it possible to import html pages into Balsamiq?

Tags: wireframe, balsamiq

Or is there a similar program that will allow this?

I want to be able to take the existing pages of my website, and turn it into wireframe form to experiment with new flows and systems.

Comment: Closest to this is "Sketch it" but the image won't be editable.

Answer (score 0):

I usually take a screenshot of my existing page and paste it into Balsamiq, making it the background. Then I use all of the other Balsamiq features to draw on top of the existing page. It really helps make sure sizes are realistic, too.